# How change crypto provider in OpenSSL and make key in Windows Computer My store as exportable?

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

What did I miss in my code: it do not have correct provider - I need: "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0" and certificate in store does not have private key: "when I press manage private keys" - it says - there is no private keys.

```
EVP_PKEY* GenerateRsaKeyPair(int keyStrength)
{
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);

    if (nullptr == ctx)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to generate ctx contex for RSA Key pair." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to intialize ctx contex for RSA Key pair." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, keyStrength) <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to set bits for ctx contex for RSA Key pair." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    EVP_PKEY* pKey = nullptr;

    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pKey) <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to generate RSA Key pair." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

    return pKey;
}

X509* GenerateSelfSignedCertificate(EVP_PKEY* pKey, const unsigned char* issuer, int days)
{
    if (nullptr == pKey)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to generate certificate because for RSA Keys are not provided." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (nullptr == issuer)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to generate certificate because an issuer is not provided." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    X509* x509 = X509_new();
    if (nullptr == x509)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create X509 object." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (X509_set_version(x509, 2) != 1) // version 3 is internal number 2
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set certificate version." << std::endl;
        X509_free(x509);
        return nullptr;
    }
    // Generate a large random serial number
    long long r = rand() % 999;
    long long serial = std::time(0) * 1000 + r;  // Current time in seconds since epoch * 1000 + random number
    BIGNUM* bignum = BN_new();
    BN_set_word(bignum, serial);

    ASN1_INTEGER* aserial = BN_to_ASN1_INTEGER(bignum, NULL);
    X509_set_serialNumber(x509, aserial);
    BN_free(bignum);
    ASN1_INTEGER_free(aserial);

    if (X509_set_pubkey(x509, pKey) != 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set public key of certificate." << std::endl;
        X509_free(x509);
        return nullptr;
    }
    // Set certificate fields
    auto xname = X509_get_subject_name(x509);
    X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(xname, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC, issuer, -1, -1, 0);
    X509_set_issuer_name(x509, xname);

    // Set validity of certificate
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), (long)60 * 60 * 24 * days);
    int ret = X509_set_pubkey(x509, pKey);

    if (ret != 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set public key of X509." << std::endl;
        X509_free(x509);
        return nullptr;
    }
    // Extensions
    X509_EXTENSION* ex;
    X509V3_CTX ctx;

    // Set up the context structure.
    X509V3_set_ctx_nodb(&ctx);
    X509V3_set_ctx(&ctx, x509, x509, NULL, NULL, 0);

    // Create the extension.
    ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, &ctx, NID_key_usage, "critical,keyCertSign");

    // Add the extension to the certificate.
    X509_add_ext(x509, ex, -1);
    X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

    // Sign the certificate with its own private key
    if (X509_sign(x509, pKey, EVP_sha512()) == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to sign certificate x509." << std::endl;
        X509_free(x509);
        return nullptr;
    }
    return x509;
}

void SaveCertKeyPairToPFXWinStore(X509* pCert, EVP_PKEY* pPrivateKey, const std::string& password)
{
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = nullptr;
    HCERTSTORE hMemoryStore = nullptr;
    HCERTSTORE hImportedStore = nullptr;
    PKCS12* p12 = nullptr;

    // Create a new PKCS12 object
    p12 = PKCS12_create(password.c_str(), "MyCertificate", pPrivateKey, pCert, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (!p12)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error creating PKCS12 structure: " << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    hMemoryStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"MY");

    if (hMemoryStore == NULL)
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Error opening store: " << errCode << std::endl;
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        return;
    }
    // Convert PKCS12 object to CRYPT_DATA_BLOB
    CRYPT_DATA_BLOB pfxBlob;
    pfxBlob.pbData = NULL;
    pfxBlob.cbData = 0;

    int pfxSize = i2d_PKCS12(p12, &pfxBlob.pbData);
    if (pfxSize < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cannot allocate memory for PKCS12 blob: " << std::endl;
        CertCloseStore(hMemoryStore, 0);
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        return;
    }
    const wchar_t* wzPassword = convertToWideChar(password.c_str());

    pfxBlob.cbData = pfxSize;
    hImportedStore = PFXImportCertStore(&pfxBlob, wzPassword, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE);

    if (nullptr == hImportedStore)
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Error importing PFX to store: " << errCode << std::endl;

        OPENSSL_free(pfxBlob.pbData);
        CertCloseStore(hMemoryStore, 0);
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        return;
    }
    pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hImportedStore, NULL);

    if (pCertContext == NULL)
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Error enumerating certificates in store: " << errCode << std::endl;
        CertCloseStore(hImportedStore, 0);
        CertCloseStore(hMemoryStore, 0);
        OPENSSL_free(pfxBlob.pbData);
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        return;
    }

    if (!CertAddCertificateContextToStore(hMemoryStore, pCertContext, CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING, NULL))
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Error adding certificate context to store: " << errCode << std::endl;
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
        CertCloseStore(hImportedStore, 0);
        CertCloseStore(hMemoryStore, 0);
        OPENSSL_free(pfxBlob.pbData);
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        return;
    }
    
    CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
    CertCloseStore(hImportedStore, 0);
    CertCloseStore(hMemoryStore, 0);
    OPENSSL_free(pfxBlob.pbData);
    PKCS12_free(p12);
}
```

If I save the certificate to pfx file using other code and import with using powershell then I can export the key and when I tested the file with:

`Certutil -privatekey -p test -dump new.pfx`

I see:

`Provider = Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider`

But I what to see:

`Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0`

Comment: What size RSA key? Why does it matter to your use case? Is the enhanced provider available on your system? Which country are you in? Edit your post with more details. Note: I am not sure which order `certutil` selects providers, but it is not making the choice based on your key/certificate. For almost all use cases it does not matter which one certutil selects.

Comment: Update your post with answers. Please do not use comments.

Comment: What size RSA key?- 2048 Why does it matter to your use case? - service using certificate does not work with different one.   Is the enhanced provider available on your system? Yes, Which country are you in? CA

Comment: Your problem is not with the provider. RSA is supported by both.

Comment: My problem only one - I want to have "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0". I know how to make it with Windows Cryptographic API  but I want to make the same with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone I fix the problem by adding rights keys:
hImportedStore = PFXImportCertStore(&pfxBlob, wzPassword
, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET | PKCS12_INCLUDE_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);